# Supabase reset password in Flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase

I have some issues with the reset password with Supabase and Flutter. I am using supabase_flutter ^0.3.1+3 and this is my code:

In my login page, that extends AuthState, I have a text button that navigate to a new page, in which you can insert your email and on a button click I have this method:

```
Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
try {
  await _auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail(
    email,
    options: AuthOptions(
      redirectTo:
          kIsWeb ? null : 'io.supabase.bearincount://reset-password/',
    ),
  );
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(SupabaseSignOutFailure(error), stackTrace);
}
```

where {{CALLBACK-URL}} is the redirect url.
In the email there is a link link with the url that look like this:

```
https://{{SOMETHING}}.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token={{USER-TOKEN}}&type=recovery&redirect_to={{CALLBACK-URL}}
```

Clicking on this link from my phone opens Safari (in iOS) and asks me if I want to open the link with my app. And here comes the problem: I succesfully open the link with my app, but it doesn't automatically navigate to the right page (the page "Reset password" with two text form field and a button). This is the rest of my code:

Login

```
class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends AuthState<LoginView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.status.isSuccess) {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
                (route) => false);
          }
          if (state.status.isFailure) {
            if (state.loginError is InvalidCredentialsException) {
              getErrorSnackbar(
                context,
                AppLocalizations.of(context).loginCredentialsError,
              );
              context.read<LoginBloc>().add(ResetStatusAfterError());
            } else {
              getErrorSnackbar(
                context,
                AppLocalizations.of(context).loginError,
              );
              context.read<LoginBloc>().add(ResetStatusAfterError());
            }
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: size.width * 0.1,
                    right: size.width * 0.1,
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const _Header(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      const _EmailInput(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      const _PasswordInput(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      const _ForgotPassword(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: const [
                          _SignUpButton(),
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          _LoginButton(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AuthState

```
class AuthState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends SupabaseAuthState<T> {
  @override
  void onUnauthenticated() {
    if (mounted) {
      context.read<AppBloc>().add(AppUnauthenticated());
    }
  }

  @override
  void onAuthenticated(Session session) {
    if (mounted) {
      context.read<AppBloc>().add(const AppAuthenticated());
    }
  }

  @override
  void onPasswordRecovery(Session session) {
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
              create: (_) => LoginBloc(context.read<UserRepository>()),
              child: const ResetPassword(),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  void onErrorAuthenticating(String message) {}
}
```

ForgotPassword

```
class ForgotPasswordPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.requestState == RequestState.failure) {
          getErrorSnackbar(context, AppLocalizations.of(context).requestFailed);
        }
        if (state.requestState == RequestState.success) {
          getSuccessSnackbar(context, AppLocalizations.of(context).emailSent);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  _Title(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  _EmailInput(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: _SendButton(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _SendButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SendButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final state = context.watch<LoginBloc>().state;
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => state.requestState == RequestState.inProgress
          ? null
          : context.read<LoginBloc>().add(ForgotPassword()),
      child: state.requestState == RequestState.inProgress
          ? const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              child: Loader(),
            )
          : Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).send),
    );
  }
}
```

ResetPassword
class ResetPassword extends StatelessWidget {
const ResetPassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          _Title(),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          _PasswordInput(),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          _ConfirmPasswordInput(),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          _ConfirmButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Basically what i whish to achieve is this: user goes to login page, click on 'forgot password', insert the email and send the request. As they receive the email and click on the link they will be redirected to the app and in the reset password page. This last part is the one it seems I cannot achieve. Any help is well apreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console, or is it just not calling `onPasswordRecovery` without any error messages?

Comment: No errors in console, unfortunately I'd say, at least I would have a lead on how to solve this problem. It is just not calling the onPasswordRecovery, as you said.

Answer (score 3):

I could not get to the bottom of the specific issue, but I got it working with the most recent supabase_flutter developer preview package that you can get [here](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter/versions/1.0.0-dev.4).

You can listen to auth state change and redirect users to different pages like this:

```dart
Supabase.instance.client.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) {
  if (event == AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery) {
    // redirect user to password recovery page
  }
});
```

Note that the package is still a developer preview, so there might be some breaking changes. However, it is using a lot of the new syntax that will be introduced officially when supabase_flutter 1.0 is released, so it might not be a bad option to start using it!

You can read more about the updates on this developer preview [here](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-flutter-sdk-1-developer-preview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had already seen the new features in 1.0 dev, I know a lot of things were improved, but I wanted to stay in the stable version until the official release. I didn't really like the idea to go to production with dev version of supabase, but since there seems no good alternative ways, I think I'll consider it if it'll be stable enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @carloberd Makes sense why you wanted to use the stable version. There might still be some breaking changes coming, so cannot promise how stable it will be. Let me look into the issue on the stable version again.

Comment: Would event be triggered on mobile app if you click on the link on different device e.g. desktop? Account gets activated, but I can't get the: `passwordRecovery` event.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue The event will only be triggered on the device that you open the recovery link with.

Comment: How can I modify the user when I am in NotAuthenticate state?

Comment: @Rafiul What exactly do you mean? If the user is not signed in, there is no user to modify.

Comment: I want to implement forgot password system before the user signs in. Can you tell me how to do that or I should create a separate question for that?

Comment: @Rafiul Yes, creating a separate question is always recommended in StackOverflow.